# Prototype cells different from dynamically created cells

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have created two types of prototype cells in storyboard. The dimension of one of them have been customized to accomodate `UIButton` object. However when the cells are created, they have the standard height. I can see the `UIButton` object but it gets truncated because of the cell height.

Why are the newly created cells different from the prototype cells?

The relevant section of the code is as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if(cell == nil)
    {

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PictureSelectionCell"];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        pictureButtonProperty = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
    }
}
```

Going forward, what are my options for creating the cell of the width (or dimensions) defined in the storyboard? Programmatically, I will be able to achieve this by creating a `CGRect` object with the specified dimensions and then create a cell using `initWithFrame`. However, I would like to avoid doing things manually.

Thanks for your response.

Comment: **Firstly** You say you have two types of prototype cells in your storyboard, but this method only loads one type.

Comment: **Secondly** More informational, but you don't need the `if` statement. You declare a cell and then check for nil (which it will be, thanks to LLVM) so the set up is always going to be done. With storyboards, all you need to do is call the dequeueReusableCell… method and if there isn't a cell in the reuse queue, then it will be created for you.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you can always set it with code

```
   -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YOUR_ROW_HEIGHT;
}
```

other way if you choose your UITableView if the storyboard, under the size inspector change the Row Height.

[image: Setting Row Height]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Give me a min while I try your code. I have set the row height in storyboard, but it does not help. That's the reason why I posted this question.

Comment: I know exactly what you are talking about. :-) I have already tried changing it, but it did not work for me. Did it work for you? Btw.. the method that you mentioned works perfectly.

Comment: maybe you needed to change the in the cell attributes, have you tried to change that as well?